# Aggregate a subtotal column based on two dates of that same row

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Situation:**

I have 5 columns

- id
- subtotal (price of item)
- order_date (purchase date)
- updated_at (if refunded or any other status change)
- status

**Objective**:

I need the order date as column 1
I need to get the subtotal for each day regardless if of the status as column 2
I need the subtotal amount for refunds for the third column.

**Example:**

If a purchase is made on May 1st and refunded on May 3rd. The output should look like this

```
+-------+----------+--------+
| date  | subtotal | refund |
+-------+----------+--------+
| 05-01 |    10.00 |   0.00 |
| 05-02 |    00.00 |   0.00 |
| 05-03 |    00.00 |  10.00 |
+-------+----------+--------+
```

while the row will look like that

```
+-----+----------+------------+------------+----------+
| id  | subtotal | order_date | updated_at |  status  |
+-----+----------+------------+------------+----------+
| 123 |       10 | 2019-05-01 | 2019-05-03 | refunded |
+-----+----------+------------+------------+----------+
```

**Query:**

Currently what I have looks like this: 
Note: Timezone discrepancy therefore bring back the dates by 8 hours.

```
;with cte as (
    select id as orderid
        , CAST(dateadd(hour,-8,order_date) as date) as order_date
        , CAST(dateadd(hour,-8,updated_at) as date) as updated_at
        , subtotal
        , status
    from orders
    )

select 
    b.dates
    , sum(a.subtotal_price) as subtotal
    , -- not sure how to aggregate it to get the refunds
from Orders as o
inner join cte as a on orders.id=cte.orderid
inner join (select * from cte where status = ('refund')) as b on o.id=cte.orderid
where dates between '2019-05-01' and '2019-05-31'
group by dates
```

And do I need to join it twice? Hopefully not since my table is huge.

Comment: Your columns don't have a time property, so how can they only be 8 hours out? If something was bough at `2019-07-15T08:50:00` then 8 hours before would be the same day but you're query (due to the data having no `time` property) would show that as `2019-07-14`, which is wrong.

Comment: there's a time property. just for the sake of simplicity, i've ommitted it in my example.

Comment: Then I'd suggest using [`AT TIME ZONE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead to change the timezone of your `datetimeoffset` (or UTC stored `datetime(2)`), as I doubt the timezone always differs by 8 hours due to Daylight Saving Time.

Comment: absolutely, didn't think of that! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a job for a [Calendar Table](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/steps/bones-of-sql-the-calendar-table). Bit of a stab in the dark, but:

```
--Overly simplistic Calendar table
CREATE TABLE dbo.Calendar (CalendarDate date);

WITH N AS(
     SELECT N
     FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
     FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4, N N5) --Many years of data
INSERT INTO dbo.Calendar
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, T.I, 0)
FROM Tally T;
GO

SELECT C.CalendarDate AS [date],
       CASE C.CalendarDate WHEN V.order_date THEN subtotal ELSE 0 END AS subtotal,
       CASE WHEN C.CalendarDate = V.updated_at AND V.[status] = 'refunded' THEN subtotal ELSE 0.00 END AS subtotal
FROM (VALUES(123,10.00,CONVERT(date,'20190501'),CONVERT(date,'20190503'),'refunded'))V(id,subtotal,order_date,updated_at,status)
     JOIN dbo.Calendar C ON V.order_date <= C.CalendarDate AND V.updated_at >= C.CalendarDate;

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.Calendar;
```

Comment: i assume there's no way of doing it without a tally?

Comment: To create the calendar table, @RogerSteinberg? You only need the Tally once and then your object is permanent, and a tally is by far the best way to create a Calendar object.

Comment: do you know how i could change my dateadd function for the timezone ? i tried using it as such: order_date at time zone 'Dateline Standard Time' as dates_zone but its not doign anything

Comment: I'd need consumable sample data for that, @RogerSteinberg. You'll be better off asking that as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider joining on a recursive CTE of sequential dates:

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2019-01-01') AS rec_date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d, 1, CONVERT(datetime, rec_date))
    FROM  dates 
    WHERE rec_date < '2019-12-31'
),    
   cte AS (
    SELECT id AS orderid
        , CAST(dateadd(hour,-8,order_date) AS date) as order_date
        , CAST(dateadd(hour,-8,updated_at) AS date) as updated_at
        , subtotal
        , status
    FROM orders
    )

SELECT rec_date AS date,
       CASE 
          WHEN c.order_date = d.rec_date THEN subtotal
          ELSE 0
       END AS subtotal,

       CASE 
          WHEN c.updated_at = d.rec_date THEN subtotal
          ELSE 0
       END AS refund

FROM cte c
JOIN dates d ON d.rec_date BETWEEN c.order_date AND c.updated_at
WHERE c.status = 'refund'
option (maxrecursion 0)

GO
```

[Rextester demo](https://rextester.com/AAI15135)